# Can't automatically choose file on <input type="file"> by using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I ran webdriver, everything was great, until OS file browser pop-ups and webdriver can't interact with it so it can't automatically choose the file on file browser.
So how can I choose the file on file browser automatically?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: what is the error you are getting share it along with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you click an upload button?

Instead you'll want to find the input element with the type 'file'. Once you've located this, perform a send keys command with the file location.

E.g.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("File Location") ;
```